# How can I change the interval of LocationRequest

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I set my application to get location notification every 5 seconds.

```
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000/6);
    myLocationReq.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest
```

so - every 5 seconds, onLocationChanged is being called.
This is working fine.

Now I want to change the interval to be 1 second, without calling

```
     requestLocationUpdates
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Did you happen to solve this yet?

Comment: no. It seems like you must call requestLocationUpdates whenever you want to change the interval. the main problem with that is that you might get a location notification immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer isn't too late, but simply create a LocationRequest object, with the desired setInterval value. And then just call requestLocationUpdates with it.

I used this with tabs where 1 tab had to get location updates faster than the others. So I just changed the interval in the onResume and onPause methods.