# Change variable with button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, variables, button

I have one simple question:
How can I change variables on picture below (INTERVAL and FASTEST_INTERVAL):
[image]

using button? I tried with this:
[image]

, and Toast message appears, but I don't think variable is really changed.

Actually, all I want is to change INTERVAL within this:
[image]

with a simple click of a button.

Comment: Does the toast message have the new increased value or no?

Comment: Yes, it does, Pedja.

Comment: Then call `mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL)` again with new updated variable.

Comment: [Like so?](http://i.imgur.com/G6D8Ay5.png) It doesn't work. Again, just within a Toast message is changed...

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423293/how-can-i-change-the-interval-of-locationrequest and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you update the interval just call the [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) function again to refresh it.